# "Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given ...." is $\epsilon < 1$ ok?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

In limit definitions, is it a requirement that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, or can I choose to work with small $\epsilon$, say below $1$?

Comment: You can as well choose $\;0<\epsilon<0.000001\;$ if you want...but **still** it must be arbitrary within this small range.

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. But most often, one wishes to show that something is true for *arbitrarily small* $\epsilon$. In that case, you can do it, just as @meesdevries says.

Comment: if you show something is smaller than $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon<1$, then it is automatically smaller than all numbers bigger than one

Answer (score 3):

Without loss of generality, you can restrict yourself to $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, or more generally, $\epsilon \in (0,a)$ for each $a > 0$.

To make this formal, you can always modify your argument as follows. You open with, "Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Define $\epsilon' = \min(\epsilon,a/2)$." Then you carry out your ordinary argument using $\epsilon'$. Finally, at the end where you conclude
$$
... < \epsilon'
$$
you finish with "and $\epsilon' \leq \epsilon$".

Answer (score -2):

$\epsilon$ is arbitrary in definition. For every $\epsilon>0$ there must be a $\delta$ so that the definition holds - it means that definition must be satisfied for every positive $\epsilon$.

If you take for example $\epsilon = 0.5$, consider function:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
 0.1& \text{ if } x \in \mathbb Q \\ 
 0& \text{ if } x \in \mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q  
\end{cases}$

This function has no limit at any $x$ but if we worked with $\epsilon = 0.5$ definition would hold - we could say that it has a limit.